# Dropzone forces another javascript function

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js on my page. Everything works fine except javascript function that creates flash messages at top right corner of page.
When I remove Dropzone.js from my page, also flash messages work fine, but when I put it back, they just don't show.

Anyone please know, how to solve this problem? I mean, it's not HUGE problem, I can handle it without flash messages on that page, but it's kind of annoying...

Here is code for flash messages displaying:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        toastr[{{$flashMessage['type']}}]({{$flashMessage['message']}})
    });
```

I tried to change `$(document).ready(function() ....` to `$(function() {...` but it didn't help. Now I have no clue, where could be the problem, so I appreciate every advice how to solve this. BTW There is no error in console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself: I removed `$(document.ready(function()...)` and it works now.